# How to list portion of subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, lists, links

Right now I have a list of questions which I labeled.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \section{Project}
    This is a researsch report.

    \subsection{Objective}
    Blablabla.

    \noindent\newline
    \large\textit{"Is this the main question?"}

    \noindent\newline
    sub questions:

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textit{Q \roman*}, ref=\textit{Question \roman*}]
      \item \label{q1} {\normalsize\textit{"What is this question?"}}
      \item \label{q2} {\normalsize\textit{"Why is this a question?"}}
      \item \label{q3} {\normalsize\textit{"How is this a question?"}}
    \end{enumerate}
    \noindent

    \section{Research}
    Blablabla.

    \subsection{\ref{q1}: What is this question?}
    Blablabla.

    \subsection{\ref{q2}: Why is this a question?}
    Blablabla.

    \subsection{\ref{q3}: How is this a question?}
    Blablabla.

\end{document}
```

Which results in to:

[image]

***Example:*** [in overleaf.](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fyqfgwzbfgbt)

The problem with this is that the subsection headers link to the list, and it would be more comprehensible that this would go the other way around. So that I label the headers and add an alternative counting in the headers and then generate a list out of this.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a new counter and `\refstepcounter`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% New counter for questions
\newcounter{question}
% Questions are labelled using lower case roman numerals
\renewcommand\thequestion{\roman{question}}

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \section{Project}
    This is a researsch report.

    \subsection{Objective}
    Blablabla.

    \noindent\newline
    \large\textit{"Is this the main question?"}

    \noindent\newline
    sub questions:

    \begin{itemize}
      \item[Q \ref{what}]  {\normalsize\textit{"What is this question?"}}
      \item[Q \ref{why}]  {\normalsize\textit{"Why is this a question?"}}
      \item[Q \ref{how}]  {\normalsize\textit{"How is this a question?"}}
    \end{itemize}
    \noindent

    \section{Research}
    Blablabla.

    % Increment the question counter while also setting \ref to its value
    \refstepcounter{question}
    % Set "what" to \ref, which is the counter's value
    \label{what}
    % Use the counter's value for the subsection title
    \subsection{Question \thequestion: What is this question?}
    Blablabla.

    \refstepcounter{question}
    \label{why}
    \subsection{Question \thequestion: Why is this a question?}
    Blablabla.

    \refstepcounter{question}
    \label{how}
    \subsection{Question \thequestion: How is this a question?}
    Blablabla.

\end{document}
```

And instead of repeating those three lines for each subsection which answers a question, I would create a new command:

```latex
\newcommand\qsubsection[2]{
  \refstepcounter{question}
  \label{#1}
  \subsection{Question \thequestion: #2}
}
```

and then write, for instance,

```latex
 \qsubsection{what}{What is this question?}
    Blablabla.
```

Comment: Really good thanks, is there a possibility to automatically create a list of the counted items? As far as I know latex this is impossible because you need multiple runs, or at least it is possible with multiple runs. If you know how to do it please collaborate.